# how to fix "ERC20: insufficient allowance" error?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transfer, erc-20-approve

I wrote a very simple contract to use the erc20 functions in another contract and the first thing I tried was transferFrom function, which works perfectly when I'm sending tokens from msg.sender(which is the address that deployed both contracts) to the transfer contract and to another addresses,
but the problems comes along  when I'm trying to use another address as my _from address and I get the error **"ERC20: insufficient allowance"** I have used increase allowance for both addresses they have the needed allowance but I still get the error.

token contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("new token", "NT") {
      _mint(msg.sender, 5000);
    }
}
```

transfer contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TransferToken {
    address owner;
    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function name() public view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return ERC20(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138).name();
    }
    

    function balanceOf(address _from) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return ERC20(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138).balanceOf(_from);
    }

    function transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) public virtual returns (bool) {
        return ERC20(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138).transferFrom(_from, _to, _amount);
    }

    
}
```

**replace the erc20 address in transfer contract**

Comment: Consider reading the [ERC-20 Token Standard](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/).

Comment: @Kerry99 yes actually that fixes all of it, thanks!!!